# check if identical row exists before insert into database table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert

My users have the ability to connect with each other, or to connect with the other profile & all connections of that profile at the same time.

But it might be, that the user is already connected with one of the connections from the other user. I need to make sure there won't be two identical rows in the database:

my query looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['crewconnect'])) {

    include '../php/dbconnect.php';

    $connections = $DBcon->query("SELECT connection_id FROM tbl_current_userconnections WHERE user_id=$profileID");
    while($row = $connections->fetch_array()){
        $crewmemberID = $row['connection_id'];

        $DBcon->query("DELETE FROM tbl_former_userconnections WHERE user_id=$activeID AND connection_id=$crewmemberID");
        $DBcon->query("DELETE FROM tbl_former_userconnections WHERE user_id=$crewmemberID AND connection_id=$activeID");

//the following query needs to be changed:
        $DBcon->query("INSERT INTO tbl_current_userconnections(user_id, connection_id) VALUES('$activeID','$crewmemberID'),('$crewmemberID','$activeID')");
    }

    $DBcon->query("INSERT INTO tbl_current_userconnections(user_id, connection_id) VALUES('$activeID','$profileID'),('$profileID','$activeID')");

    $DBcon->close();
}
```

I thought about something like this for the part to be changed:

```
        $DBcon->query("IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT user_id, connection_id FROM tbl_current_userconnections WHERE user_id=$activeID AND connection_id=$crewmemberID)) INSERT INTO tbl_current_userconnections(user_id, connection_id) VALUES('$activeID','$crewmemberID'),('$crewmemberID','$activeID')");
```

but this is not working, so far...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to have the database do the check.  That is, let the database maintain the integrity of the data.

So, first create a unique index:

```
create unique index unq_t_userid_connectionid on tbl_current_userconnections(user_id, connection_id);
```

Then, any attempt to insert an existing value would result in an error.  If you don't want an error, then use:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_current_userconnections(user_id, connection_id) 
    VALUES ('$activeID', '$crewmemberID'),
           ('$crewmemberID', '$activeID')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id = VALUES(user_id);
```

The `ON DUPLICATE KEY` does nothing to the data, but it prevents an error from being reported.

Why is this better?  The problem with doing the check in the application is that two users might attempt to create the same link(s) at the same time.  This can result in a race condition where the `IF` passes for both users, so both insert the data.  That is one important reason why doing the logic in the database is important.

Also, you should learn to use parameterized queries and not pass values directly into query statements.  Your approach is dangerous and can lead to unexpected syntax errors.

Comment: Why are you updating `user_id` if it already exists with the same value? That option is supposed to be used to update other columns, not the key columns. If he just wants to skip the duplicate, he should use `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: @Barmar . . . The `user_id = VALUES(user_id)` is a no-op.  It does nothing (because MySQL checks if a record is changed before doing an `update`).  Well, it does one thing:  it ignores the specific error of a duplicate.  `INSERT IGNORE` ignores *all* errors on the insert, not just those caused by a duplication error.  Hence, my preference for `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Put a unique index on `(user_id, connection_id)`. Then you can use `INSERT IGNORE`. If it tries to create a duplicate row, it will simply skip those values without getting an error.